# Something went wrong: OAuthException Error validating access token

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, sdk, facebook-oauth

I'm trying to share status using facebook-sdk

when I execute this line:

```
fb_response = graph.put_wall_post('python put wall post', {},
         FACEBOOK_PROFILE_ID)
```

I get this error:

```
Something went wrong: OAuthException Error validating access token: Session has expired at unix time 1330884000. The current unix time is 1330939165.
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems clear to me, your session has expired... You have to get a new token using OAuth...